# Lua: Simplest zoom button [Corona SDK]

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, zooming

What's the simplest zoom function featuring "+/-" button in Lua [Corona SDK]?
My point is to have button (2 buttons, + and -) that does not change its size while zooming and to have overally smooth zoom that allows you to scroll background when it is zoomed. I'm basically new to coding, so I'm having some trouble with handling that. I'm making my first project (piano app), so I'd like it to be simple, I have been searching how to do that long, but I still couldn't find any exact *readable* sample of code which I would be able to use. How about your ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not understood what you want to do. But if you want to zoom an image you can change the *xScale* and the *yScale* property of an object. And you should insert the image object into a scrollview object to scroalling.

Comment: If you dont understand, it would be better to write this as a comment.

Comment: I know that, but I can not write a comment. Because I do not have this permission for that question! I get this message: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"